# Wordpress $wpdb->insert two rows on custom table for each post

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

i use custom field to insert data to my custom table named 'wp_multi_links' , i use $wpdb->insert , the probleme is when i publish new post for exemple with ID = 62 , two id's added 62 & 63 with the same custom field value , i think the problem is with post_status ,

scrreenshot of wp_posts table:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/srHjk.png

my custom field code :

```
<?php

/**
 * Adds a box to the main column on the Post and Page edit screens.
 */
function myplugin_add_meta_box() {

    $screens = array( 'post');

    foreach ( $screens as $screen ) {

        add_meta_box(
            'myplugin_sectionid',
            __( 'My Post Section Title', 'myplugin_textdomain' ),
            'myplugin_meta_box_callback',
            $screen
        );
    }
}
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'myplugin_add_meta_box' );

/**
 * Prints the box content.
 * 
 * @param WP_Post $post The object for the current post/page.
 */
function myplugin_meta_box_callback( $post ) {

    // Add an nonce field so we can check for it later.
    wp_nonce_field( 'myplugin_meta_box', 'myplugin_meta_box_nonce' );

    /*
     * Use get_post_meta() to retrieve an existing value
     * from the database and use the value for the form.
     */
    $value = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_my_meta_value_key', true );

    echo '<label for="myplugin_new_field">';
    _e( 'Description for this field', 'myplugin_textdomain' );
    echo '</label> ';
    echo '<input type="text" id="myplugin_new_field" name="myplugin_new_field" value="' . esc_attr( $value ) . '" size="25" />';
}

/**
 * When the post is saved, saves our custom data.
 *
 * @param int $post_id The ID of the post being saved.
 */
function myplugin_save_meta_box_data( $post_id ) {
    global $wpdb; 
    /*
     * We need to verify this came from our screen and with proper authorization,
     * because the save_post action can be triggered at other times.
     */

    // Check if our nonce is set.
    if ( ! isset( $_POST['myplugin_meta_box_nonce'] ) ) {
        return;
    }

    // Verify that the nonce is valid.
    if ( ! wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['myplugin_meta_box_nonce'], 'myplugin_meta_box' ) ) {
        return;
    }

    // If this is an autosave, our form has not been submitted, so we don't want to do anything.
    if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) {
        return;
    }


    // Check the user's permissions.
    if ( isset( $_POST['post_type'] ) && 'page' == $_POST['post_type'] ) {

        if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_page', $post_id ) ) {
            return;
        }

    } else {

        if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post_id ) ) {
            return;
        }
    }

    /* OK, it's safe for us to save the data now. */

    // Make sure that it is set.
    if ( ! isset( $_POST['myplugin_new_field'] ) ) {
        return;
    }

    // Sanitize user input.
    $my_data = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['myplugin_new_field'] );
    // Update the meta field in the database.
    update_post_meta( $post_id, '_my_meta_value_key', $my_data );

    // isert data to DB

    $wpdb->insert( 
    'wp_multi_links', 
    array( 
        'post_id' => $post_id, 
        'link_url' => $my_data 
    ), 
    array( 
        '%d', 
        '%s'
    ) 
);

}

add_action( 'save_post', 'myplugin_save_meta_box_data' );
```

wp_multi_links table screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sPGNU.png

How i can fix this !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the `post_type` field on the row with ID 63, it's likely a `revision`.

The problem with your code is that everytime you save your post it inserts another entry into `wp_multi_links` table.

You should check if already exists an entry for `$post_id` and, if so, update it.

**Update**

This should work:

```
$data         = array( 'post_id'  => $post_id, 'link_url' => $my_data );
$data_format  = array( '%d', '%s' );
$where        = array( 'post_id' => $post_id );
$where_format = array( '%d' );

$updated = $wpdb->update( 'wp_multi_links', $data, $data_format, $where, $where_format );

if( ! $updated )
    $wpdb->insert( 'wp_multi_links', $data, $data_format );
```

Comment: thanks @d79 i think that's the trick , but how i can do that ?